# Pentoha Installation

Tags: installation

How to install Pentoha BI server? Community edition. There is  not documentation available for installation. I have tried some of the methods available on google search. But no one work for me. Does any one point me to the working documentation or blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally make it work using the below URL:

http://opensourceerpguru.com/2008/06/09/open-source-bi-pentaho-installation-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

I found [THIS](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Basic+BI+Platform+Documentation) documentation root on their site in about 3 or 4 mouse-clicks. D-, must try harder ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I already gone through this documentation. It does not include any installation steps. That documentation is for after the installation.

Comment: I am getting the below mentioned errors while starting the pentoha apps. 

http://http://linuxtrove.com.pastebin.com/nN2BH6PD

These are cataline.out logs.

Comment: won't open for me

Comment: Please try this:

http://pastebin.com/5Gqjm1gM

Comment: I could make a few guesses looking at that log but not with any certainty - have you contacted them directly?

Comment: NO not yet! Do they have any live chat help or something..

Comment: http://www.pentaho.com/contact/